# Formal languages induced by ultrafilters

Tags: fl.formal-languages

Let $I$ be the set of all recursively enumerable languages over an alphabet $\Sigma$.
Let $$S_\alpha=\{i\in I : \alpha\in i\}$$ for all $\alpha\in\Sigma^*$.
Then $$E=\{S_\alpha:\alpha\in K\subseteq\Sigma^*\}$$ can be extended to an ultrafilter $\mathscr{U}$ since $E$ has the finite intersection property:
$$\{{\alpha_1},\dots,{\alpha_n}\}\in S_{\alpha_1}\cap\dots\cap S_{\alpha_n}\text { and }\{{\alpha_1},\dots,{\alpha_n}\}\in I \text{ since it's a finite language}$$
We can define $L=\{\alpha:\{i\in I:\alpha\in i\}\in \mathscr{U}\}$.

What is the relationship between $L$ and $K$?

Comment: Extending $E$ to $U$ means that $E \subseteq U$.  Note that $K = \{\alpha \mid S_\alpha \in E\}$ and $L = \{\alpha \mid S_\alpha \in U\}$, so $K \subseteq L$.
(This question seems like an exercise – what is your motivation for asking it?)